# Catching scroll events one time

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I am attempting to work with some scroll events and create a "snapping" effect to the top level sections of my page. I am successfully capturing everything and animating the scroll position and everything actually works, however, when I am testing for the scroll event, it is firing everytime my condition is met, so my scroll function gets called too many times. I'm wondering how to best unbind the scroll event if my condition is met(the mousewheel has moved/spun a certain amount). I'm checking for the amount scroll with the 'direction' var just after the $window.on function. Any help refactoring this or advice on how better to do tackle it is appreciated.

For the record, I'm using jquery, greensock and a greensock plugin called scrollTo.

```
$(function(){

var $window = $(window);        //Window object

var scrollTime = 1;             //Scroll time
var scrollDistance = 250;       //Distance. Use smaller value for shorter scroll and greater value for longer scroll

$window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
    var direction = delta > .875 ? 'up' : delta < -.875 ? 'down' : 'stick';

    if ( direction == 'up' ) {
        // going up...
        var next = $('.section.visible').prev('.section');
        scroll(next);
    }
    else if ( direction == 'down' ) {
        // going down to china town...
        var next = $('.section.visible').next('.section');
        scroll(next);
    }

    function scroll(next) {
        // scroll the doc
        var scroll = next.position().top;

        TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
            scrollTo : { y: scroll, autoKill:true },
                ease: Power3.easeOut,
                autoKill: true,
                overwrite: 5                            
            });

        // clean up classes
        $('.section.visible').removeClass('visible');
        next.addClass('visible');
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be debouncing. I had read about throttling vs. debouncing and didn't seems to think either of them was the answer. Thanks to Arun P Johny who got me started with what seems to be a throttling method. It eventually led me to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the tested solution in this case is to use `setTimeout()`, in the following case if two events happens within 200 milliseconds then the first one is cancelled

```
$(function(){

    var $window = $(window);        //Window object

    var scrollTime = 1;             //Scroll time
    var scrollDistance = 250;       //Distance. Use smaller value for shorter scroll and greater value for longer scroll

    $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){
        var $this = $(this);

        event.preventDefault();

        clearTimeout($this.data('scrolltimer'));

        var timer = setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
            var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
            var direction = delta > .875 ? 'up' : delta < -.875 ? 'down' : 'stick';

            if ( direction == 'up' ) {
                // going up...
                var next = $('.section.visible').prev('.section');
                scroll(next);
            }
            else if ( direction == 'down' ) {
                // going down to china town...
                var next = $('.section.visible').next('.section');
                scroll(next);
            }

            function scroll(next) {
                // scroll the doc
                var scroll = next.position().top;

                TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
                    scrollTo : { y: scroll, autoKill:true },
                    ease: Power3.easeOut,
                    autoKill: true,
                    overwrite: 5                            
                });

                // clean up classes
                $('.section.visible').removeClass('visible');
                next.addClass('visible');
            }
        }, this), 200);
        $this.data('scrolltimer', timer)

    });
});
```